# Why spring init-method destroy-method methods behaving different?

Tags: java, spring

I am new to springs. I am trying to call init and destroy method for different bean invoking

My init method is called from only "FileSystemResource" Why it was not called from others?

```
public class DefaultMessage {
    private String message = "Basic Bean injecting";

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public DefaultMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public DefaultMessage() {
    }
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("Testing init.");
    }
    public void destory(){
        System.out.println("Spring Container is destroyed.");
    }
```

My XML is

```
<bean id="basicBean" class="com.sarma.spring.core.DefaultMessage" init-method="init" destroy-method="destory"></bean>
```

Main class

```
//Type 1
ApplicationContext applicationContext =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("DefaultMessage.xml");

//Basic Bean Testing
DefaultMessage message = (DefaultMessage) applicationContext.getBean("basicBean");
log.info(message.getMessage());
log.info("---------------------------ApplicationContext End------------------------------");

//Type 2
Resource res = new FileSystemResource("C:\\Sarma\\Spring\\SpringEx\\src\\resource\\DefaultMessage.xml");
BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(res);
DefaultMessage message1 = (DefaultMessage) factory.getBean("basicBean");
log.info("Test "+message1.getMessage());
log.info("- ---------------------------FileSystemResource End------------------------------");  

//Type 3
ClassPathResource res1 = new ClassPathResource("DefaultMessage.xml");
BeanFactory factory1 = new XmlBeanFactory(res1);
DefaultMessage message2 = (DefaultMessage) factory1.getBean("basicBean");
log.info("Test "+message2.getMessage());
log.info("- ---------------------------ClassPathResource End-------------------------------");

//Type4
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"DefaultMessage.xml"});
DefaultMessage message3 = (DefaultMessage) context.getBean("basicBean");
log.info(message3.getMessage());
context.close();
log.info("- ---------------------------ConfigurableApplicationContext End------------------");
```

OUTPUT

```
2013-09-18 13:49:22 INFO  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:513 - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@913750: startup date [Wed Sep 18 13:49:22 EDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
2013-09-18 13:49:22 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:316 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [DefaultMessage.xml]
2013-09-18 13:49:22 INFO  DefaultMessageMain:27 - Basic Bean injecting
2013-09-18 13:49:22 INFO  DefaultMessageMain:29 - ---------------------------ApplicationContext End------------------------------
2013-09-18 13:49:22 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:316 - Loading XML bean definitions from file [C:\Sarma\Spring\SpringEx\src\resource\DefaultMessage.xml]
Testing init.
2013-09-18 13:49:22 INFO  DefaultMessageMain:36 - Test Basic Bean injecting
2013-09-18 13:49:22 INFO  DefaultMessageMain:37 - - ---------------------------FileSystemResource End------------------------------
2013-09-18 13:49:22 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:316 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [DefaultMessage.xml]
2013-09-18 13:49:22 INFO  DefaultMessageMain:42 - Test Basic Bean injecting
2013-09-18 13:49:22 INFO  DefaultMessageMain:43 - - ---------------------------ClassPathResource End-------------------------------
2013-09-18 13:49:22 INFO  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:513 - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@176e552: startup date [Wed Sep 18 13:49:22 EDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
2013-09-18 13:49:22 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:316 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [DefaultMessage.xml]
2013-09-18 13:49:22 INFO  DefaultMessageMain:47 - Basic Bean injecting
2013-09-18 13:49:22 INFO  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext:873 - Closing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@176e552: startup date [Wed Sep 18 13:49:22 EDT 2013]; root of context hierarchy
2013-09-18 13:49:22 INFO  DefaultMessageMain:49 - - ---------------------------ConfigurableApplicationContext End------------------
```

My init method is called from only "FileSystemResource" Why it was not called from others?

Why it is behaving different?

It never called my destroy method

Comment: I didnt miss destroy method.   
DefaultMessage" init-method="init" destroy-method="destory"></bean>

Comment: It works for me, what Spring version are you on?

Comment: What is ur output? which version of jar files ur using?

Comment: Is it calling init and destroy for all 4 types?  Sotirios Delimanolis

Comment: The output is `Closing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@176e552:...` and `Spring Container is destroyed.` from the method. I'm on 3.2

Comment: I am using Spring 4.0.0 version. I will try in 3.2 version jar and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to copy your code to explain

```
//Type 1
ApplicationContext applicationContext =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("DefaultMessage.xml");

//Basic Bean Testing
DefaultMessage message = (DefaultMessage) applicationContext.getBean("basicBean");
```

The above will `init()` your bean.

```
//Type 2
Resource res = new FileSystemResource("C:\\Sarma\\Spring\\SpringEx\\src\\resource\\DefaultMessage.xml");
BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(res);
DefaultMessage message1 = (DefaultMessage) factory.getBean("basicBean");
```

This will also `init()` your bean.

```
//Type 3
ClassPathResource res1 = new ClassPathResource("DefaultMessage.xml");
BeanFactory factory1 = new XmlBeanFactory(res1);
DefaultMessage message2 = (DefaultMessage) factory1.getBean("basicBean");
```

This will also `init()` your bean.

```
//Type4
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"DefaultMessage.xml"});
DefaultMessage message3 = (DefaultMessage) context.getBean("basicBean");
log.info(message3.getMessage());
context.close();
```

This will also `init()` your bean. Because of the `context.close()`, all beans will be destroyed before the context being closed. If the `destroy-method` isn't being called, you can try with `DisposableBean` interface, but consider that bad practice as your classes start being dependent on Spring types.

Comment: @sarma I'm having a hard time getting the 4.0.0 with maven. Try with the `DisposableBean` interface. The docs say that what you are attempting should work.

Comment: I have tried in spring 3.2, Its strange its not working in 4.0.0

Comment: @Sarma Well the current draft of the spec says it works, so they probably haven't finished that part.

Comment: Hey Sotirios Delimanolis, is there other ways to create beans?

Comment: @Sarma You mean other than from a `BeanFactory`? You can use programmatic (as opposed to xml) configuration with `@Configuration`

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis other way means Beanfactory with XML using any other class and get beanFactory reference object.
What I mean other class are ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, ClassPathResource and so on. 
I haven't started using Annotation yet.

Comment: @Sarma That's the purpose of the `BeanFactory`. I know of no other ways with Spring.

Comment: @Sarma You're welcome. Hope Spring 4.0 will behave as expected soon.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented DisposableBean interface to my bean class and overrides destroy method and removed destroy-method method form my XML.

Now destroy method is calling 3 times except ApplicationContext, 
Destroy method is calling from FileSystemResource, ClassPathResource, ClassPathXmlApplicationContext and not from ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 0):

For ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, we can pass different xml's for example

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"DefaultMessage.xml", "DefaultMessage1.xml}");
```

while closing ConfigurableApplicationContext it will close all  resource which was opened, that why it closed all 3  FileSystemResource, ClassPathResource, ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.